# Instagram's app comment box animation in nativescript

Tags: animation, nativescript

**NEW INFORMATION**
After some hours testing this was as close i could get:
[Dock stays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVW2u.gif)

And this:
[Dock vanishs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Njo2P.gif)

On the Instagram APP (android), when you want to add a comment, it opens a mini box on the bottom of the screen, and thre you write.

This box, will slide in, and slide out. It is fixed and over all the page content.

Is there a way to mount this layout preset, and animation on nativescript?

My attempt gives me a:

DockLayout
  WrapLayout (bottom) (commentbox)

StackLayout (page content)

Almost Everything works, besides when the animation took places. As the comment box moves the place where it stood is not removed. So a blank space remains as the dockLayout wont remove it util i make the commentbox removed.

Alas: I'm using nativescript-vue

```html
<DockLayout stretchLastChild="false">
  <WrapLayout ref="comm" height="auto" class="comm" dock="bottom" v-if="showComm" backgroundColor="red">
    <DockLayout class="avatar" stretchLastChild="false">
      <Image dock="bottom" width="15%" alignSelf="flex-end" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" stretch="none" />
    </DockLayout>

    <TextView editable="true" width="65%" ref="test">
      <FormattedString>
      </FormattedString>
    </TextView>

    <DockLayout stretchLastChild="false" width="15%">
      <Button dock="bottom" class="flat fas" @tap="test()" :text="'fa-play' | fonticon" flat />
    </DockLayout>
  </WrapLayout>

  <StackLayout height="100%" dock="top">
    <PullToRefresh :refreshing="loading" ref="pullToRefresh" @refresh="load">
      <ListView for="item in items" @itemTap="onItemTap">
        <v-template>
          <timeline-item :data="item" />
        </v-template>
      </ListView>
    </PullToRefresh>
  </StackLayout>
</DockLayout>
```

Comment: It's default in Android, you don't have to actually animate it. If you set your `windowSoftInputMode` on Activity to `adjustResize`, then anything you dock at the bottom of your screen will automatically adjust above keyboard. On iOS, it's KeyboardToolbar. There is a plugin too - https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-keyboard-toolbar

Comment: I'm realy new to android native. So the correct would just put the element and remove it from the view it would slow fade in and fade out? In my tests this did not happen.